# Why does collect_set aggregation add Exchange operator to join query of bucketed tables?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-2.2

I'm using Spark-2.2.
I'm POCing Spark's bucketing.
I've created a bucketed table, here's the `desc formatted my_bucketed_tbl` output:

```
+--------------------+--------------------+-------+
|            col_name|           data_type|comment|
+--------------------+--------------------+-------+
|              bundle|              string|   null|
|                 ifa|              string|   null|
|               date_|                date|   null|
|                hour|                 int|   null|
|                    |                    |       |
|# Detailed Table ...|                    |       |
|            Database|             default|       |
|               Table|             my_bucketed_tbl|
|               Owner|            zeppelin|       |
|             Created|Thu Dec 21 13:43:...|       |
|         Last Access|Thu Jan 01 00:00:...|       |
|                Type|            EXTERNAL|       |
|            Provider|                 orc|       |
|         Num Buckets|                  16|       |
|      Bucket Columns|             [`ifa`]|       |
|        Sort Columns|             [`ifa`]|       |
|    Table Properties|[transient_lastDd...|       |
|            Location|hdfs:/user/hive/w...|       |
|       Serde Library|org.apache.hadoop...|       |
|         InputFormat|org.apache.hadoop...|       |
|        OutputFormat|org.apache.hadoop...|       |
|  Storage Properties|[serialization.fo...|       |
+--------------------+--------------------+-------+
```

When I'm executing an explain of a group by query, I can see that we've spared the exchange phase :

```
sql("select ifa,max(bundle) from my_bucketed_tbl group by ifa").explain

== Physical Plan ==
SortAggregate(key=[ifa#932], functions=[max(bundle#920)])
+- SortAggregate(key=[ifa#932], functions=[partial_max(bundle#920)])
   +- *Sort [ifa#932 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
      +- *FileScan orc default.level_1[bundle#920,ifa#932] Batched: false, Format: ORC, Location: InMemoryFileIndex[hdfs://ip-10-44-9-73.ec2.internal:8020/user/hive/warehouse/level_1/date_=2017-1..., PartitionFilters: [], PushedFilters: [], ReadSchema: struct<bundle:string,ifa:string>
```

But, when I replace Spark's `max` function with `collect_set`, I can see that the execution plan is the same as a non-bucketed table, means, the exchange phase is not spared :

```
sql("select ifa,collect_set(bundle) from my_bucketed_tbl group by ifa").explain

== Physical Plan ==
ObjectHashAggregate(keys=[ifa#1010], functions=[collect_set(bundle#998, 0, 0)])
+- Exchange hashpartitioning(ifa#1010, 200)
   +- ObjectHashAggregate(keys=[ifa#1010], functions=[partial_collect_set(bundle#998, 0, 0)])
      +- *FileScan orc default.level_1[bundle#998,ifa#1010] Batched: false, Format: ORC, Location: InMemoryFileIndex[hdfs://ip-10-44-9-73.ec2.internal:8020/user/hive/warehouse/level_1/date_=2017-1..., PartitionFilters: [], PushedFilters: [], ReadSchema: struct<bundle:string,ifa:string>
```

Is there any configuration that I missed or it's a limitation that Spark's bucketing has at the moment?

Comment: Works fine with managed tables.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was fixed in version 2.2.1.
You can find the [Jira issue here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-22223)

Comment: Do you know what issue it was? Do you have a JIRA link for that?